# Spidermonkey shell. How to change encoding of source code?

Tags: spidermonkey

If I enter

```
 print("®".length)
```

in `smjs`, it prints 2. If I enter `javascript:alert("®".length)` in my firefox as well as opera, it prints 1. Rhino prints 1 too.
Is it possible to tell smjs that I want to treat such characters as single character? Os: linux(Ubuntu 9.04), locale: UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The JS shell is (maybe unfortunately :-) not locale-aware. It looks like this problem has been fixed by [Bug 648102](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648102) -- all input lines in the shell are decoded as UTF-8. Yay progress!

```
$ ./js
js> print("®".length)
1
```

And I get the same result in Firefox's fancy new JS scratchpad, which confirms your original `javascript:`-based result!